# Different candle positions in coins with same OCHL values

Tags: charts

Why do candles sometimes have different positions and sizes even when the open-close-high-low are all of the same value?

For instance in one coin I saw: DigitalNote(XDN) the price has been consistent at 0.00000030 for a while, yet the candles are of different sizes.

[image]

In this image, the last two candles both have O=0.00000030 C=0.0000030 H=0.0000030 L=0.0000030

Yet somehow the candles are of different sizes.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Something isn't right. If all OHLC values are the same, then there should only be a single dash, which looks like a hyphen as opposed to the bars that you show in your picture. A bar indicates that there was a price fluctuation in the recorded time period. 
What I have found in my exploring of various API providers is that there are many that don't understand how to implement candle charts, or how to calculate candle data. I think the problem is that so many people in the community know about cryptocurrencies, but don't have a clue as it applies to financial charting and trade signals in general. For these reasons, I use [ClueDex](https://www.cluedex.com/api) for my OHLCV data provider as they seem to have figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind exchange data might not be reliable in all instances due to the way they have it implemented. Your best bet is to see if the exchange can provide a data field of historic prices and then plot it yourself using excel.